# Gnome session listen on tcp ports

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kali-linux

I'm using kali virtual machine and after a recent update strange thing happens
gnome-session starts listening on random tcp ports
here's the output of netstat -nltp

`Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40117           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      917/gnome-session-b 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38071           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      586/gnome-session-b 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      555/postgres

tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      555/postgres

tcp6       0      0 :::33405                :::*                    LISTEN      586/gnome-session-b 
tcp6       0      0 :::41315                :::*                    LISTEN      917/gnome-session-b`

how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems as a bug,
https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/86zxf8/gnomesessionbinary_listening_on_tcp_socket/

and can confirm it is gone at version 3.28.0-2